# Listing a post's categories and subcategories

Tags: single, categories

Is there a way to display the parent categories and subcategories for a particular post (ie. for use on `single.php`).

I've tried using [`get_the_category_list()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category_list/), but it displays a list like this:

- Subcat1
- ParentCat1
- Subcat2
- Subcat3
- ParentCat2

Even if you try the 'single' or 'multiple' display argument, it doesn't give me what I want, which is this:

- ParentCat1

  - Subcat1
  - Subcat2
- ParentCat2

  - Subcat 3

Is it possible to get the categories to be displayed like this? Even using another method (like `get_terms()`)?

Comment: though, i haven't tried, the get_the_category_list function has an optional paremeter on how to display the parents -> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category_list

Comment: @gdaniel Yep, but it doesn't appear to do the above as far as I can tell. It takes two options: 'single' or 'multiple'.

Comment: Please elaborate on the "subcategories for a particular post" part? Do you mean post category siblings?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Update 1:

Thanks to [@birgire](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/26350/birgire) for suggesting a better way:

```
wp_list_categories( [ 'include' => wp_list_pluck( get_the_category(), 'term_id' ) ] );
```

---

Try this in your `single.php` template:

```
$current_cats = get_the_category();
$current_cats_ids = [];

foreach ($current_cats as $cat) {
    $current_cats_ids[] = $cat->term_id;
}

wp_list_categories([
    'include' => $current_cats_ids,
]);
```

Comment: This assumes the user has selected the parent(s) category as well? I guess we could wrap this into: `wp_list_categories( [ 'include' => wp_list_pluck( get_the_category(), 'term_id' ) ] );`  for the compact version  ;-)

Comment: @birgire :]] haven't known that WordPress has that badass function. Let me update the answer :)

Comment: ps: just a note that if the include array is empty then `wp_list_categories` will show all the tree. But afaik there's always the fallback category (usually "uncategorized") so under normal circumstances it's not empty. But it's easy to fix that if necessary.

Comment: Why isn't `include` mentioned as an argument in the documentation? (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_list_categories/) Arg.

Comment: There are missing arguments in the function's docblock, like `style`, `pad_counts`, `class` and `walker`? and then there are all the arguments supported by `get_categories()` or `get_terms()`, like `include` etc. I filed the ticket [#36693](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/36693)  yesterday @DjangoReinhardt

Comment: @birgire Good job! It's maddening when you've read the documentation and can't see a way to do things, only to discover the documentation is incomplete. Next time I'll make sure to read all the user contributed notes, too. I had no idea that WP's documentation could be so flaky.

Comment: Yes it can be difficult. The old Codex on codex.wordpress.org was often out-of-sync with the current core code, but I think the new Codex on developer.wordpress.org is now auto-generated from code, so that shows how important it is to have the inline-docs correct ;-) @DjangoReinhardt